# Problem adding files starting with dot to repository

Tags: git

I started to use a git repo to backup config files, also in "/etc", using "/" as work-tree, and created an alias, called "git-backup", to this command:

```
git --work-tree=/ --git-dir=/home/user/repo/.git
```

This seems to work well for few years but now it's broken: I can't add file, well really can't add ".config" files, even with -f option; and if I try to add a folder inside home directory:

```
git-backup add src/linux-5.10.147
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
home
hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addIgnoredFile false"
```

I'm using

```
git-backup config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

and ".gitignore_global" file is:

```
# First, ignore everything
*
# Now, whitelist anything that's a directory
#!*/
# And all the file types you're interested in.
!/etc/*
!/home/user/*
```

The file ".git/info/exclude" has all lines commented out.

I'm using a repo with only readme file, I clone it, and point git-dir defined in the alias to the .git dir in the cloned repo.

Any advise or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to git documentation, your .gitignore file should not work:

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file
> excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It is not
> possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is
> excluded.** Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance
> reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter
> where they are defined. Put a backslash ("") in front of the first
> "!" for patterns that begin with a literal "!", for example,
> "!important!.txt".

Try to change your .gitignore file to reinclude the directories themselves:

```
!/etc
!/home          # Reinclude home ...
/home/*         # ... but exclude all sub-directories of home ...
!/home/user/*   # ... except user
```

Comment: thanks for point that out. Still can't get the user directory to be tracked. The problem could be related to alias definition??

Comment: From documentation: `If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular .gitignore file itself. Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the .gitignore level.` So if I have .gitignore_global inside user folder all path are relative to user folder?